# How to disable faulty detection for a problem in Problems view?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code for writing PHP code and the VS Code "Problems" view shows an invalid problem:

```
Expected type 'object'. Found 'null'.
```

This is caused by PHP code that logically looks like

```
function foo(\MyNameSpace\MyObjectType $myobj)
{
  try
  {
     // lots of code
  }
  catch (Throwable $e)
  {
     $myobj->someMethod(); // this causes Problem view to claim that $myobj is null!
  }
}
```

so obviously the test that throws up this problem is broken. **Can I somehow disable this specific (false positive) test and keep the the other possibly detected problems?** As this is a generic issue with VS Code only, I'd rather not add any markup in the actual source code to workaround the problem. This would also help to ignore problems that are caused with different expectations of code style, in case such "problems" were found. Note that I'm looking for a possibility to disable the test workspace wide or user wide, not for any specific line or file only.

In case some test (e.g. the above `Expected type 'object'. Found 'null'.`) is flakey, I'd rather simply disable the whole test than try to fight with it in any files in my workspace. I think the optimal feature I'm looking for would be "disable/ignore this test for 4 weeks/for this version of Visual Studio Code" in case the test is fixed in some future release.

Comment: Which extension reports this problem? I use PHP Intelephense.

Comment: The full message says `Expected type 'object'. Found 'null'.` in black letters followed by `intelephense(1006) [Ln 776, Col 3]` in grey letters (and this problem is incorrectly reported for all uses of $myobj within that `catch` block because the actual code is not just a single line of code). Note that I'm looking for a generic way to disable selected tests, not a fix for this specific problem.

Comment: I guess some code (like `$myobj = foo()`) in the try block make the analyzer believe this variable is null. Sure you can disable the test by unchecking **Intelephense > Diagnostics: Type Errors**

Comment: There's a statement `$myobj = null` as the last line of the `try` block (to trigger PHP to free the RAM immediately). That cannot obviously throw so `catch` block cannot ever execute after that, so this is just faulty diagnostics. I think I will go with `File` - `Preferences` - `Settings` - `Extensions` and disable the `Diagnostics: Type Errors` even though it will disable many other tests as a side-effect, too.

Comment: (Destructors cannot throw in PHP. If destructors could throw, then I'd agree that $myobj could be null while entering the `catch` block.)

Comment: Replacing the line with `unset($myobj)` should work.

Comment: Yeah, using `unset($myobj)` instead of `$myobj = null` avoids this issue. However, I'm looking for more general answer which is not related to this specific case because there will be always tests that cause false positives with real world code.

Comment: @shingo Is there a generic way to figure out which error class (e.g. here "Type Errors") one should disable when you only see an error message in the "Problems" view? I understand that the grey text includes info about the correct extension. Is the number `1006` intelephense version number of error class identifier? If it's error class identifier, is there a way to map it to error type `Type Errors` without access to intelephense source code?

Comment: Not available yet I think: https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/568